# Replace positions with another positions in file

Tags: awk

I've a flat file with fixed record length (~2500)

```
H20190105                         
D0012345APPLE INC      100001072010
D0008912SAMSUNG        450023082005
T0001245678
```

- Position 2-8 A/C# (left padded with zeros)
- Position 9-23 A/C Name (right padded with spaces)
- Position 24 rest of the fields

I need to mask account name field (position 9-23) in the file to ACCT_A/C# by removing leading zeroes from A/C#

Desired result as below

```
H20190105
D0012345ACCT_12345     100001072010
D0008912ACCT_8912      450023082005
T0001245678
```

I used below command, but couldn't remove leading zeros from A/C#.

```
awk '/^D/{$0=substr($0,1,8)"ACCT_"substr($0,2,7)"  "substr($0,24,length($0))} 1' FILE.TXT > OUT.TXT
```

Using `int(substr($0,2,7))` to trim zeros makes the next field position to be altered.

Can anyone help to get the desired result?

Comment: Is that a tab character between the columns on the lines that have two columns?

Comment: No delimiters. Fields with fixed position. Trailing spaces if field value is less than defined field length.

Answer (score 2):

A fairly short `awk` one-liner:

```
$ awk '/^D/ { nr = substr($0,2,7); $0 = sprintf("D%07dACCT_%-10d%s", nr, nr, substr($0,24)) } { print }' file
H20190105
D0012345ACCT_12345     100001072010
D0008912ACCT_8912      450023082005
T0001245678
```

The `awk` code would detect the lines that need modifying by the presence of a `D` in the first position.

The new line is constructed with `sprintf()` from the zero-filled number after `D`, the string `ACCT_` followed by the same number again (now not zero-filled), and finally whatever was in and after position 24 on the line.

All lines (modified as described above, or not modified at all) are printed.

Comment: Thank you very much! Using sprintf in awk is simple and effective.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ perl -pe 's/^(D)(.{7})(.{12})/sprintf("%s%s%s%-7s",$1,$2,"ACCT_",$2+0)/e' input.txt 
H20190105                         
D0012345ACCT_12345     100001072010
D0008912ACCT_8912      450023082005
T0001245678
```

This uses perl's `e` modifier to the `s/LHS/RHS/` operator, so that it executes the RHS as perl code.  The `$2+0` implicitly converts $2 from a zero-padded string to a number, which automatically strips any leading zeroes.   The `sprintf()` format makes sure that the output line has exactly the same field lengths as the input.

---

Or, to fix your `awk` one-liner:

```
$ awk '/^D/{$0=substr($0,1,8)"ACCT_"sprintf("%-7s",substr($0,2,7)+0)"  "substr($0,24,length($0))} 1' input.txt 
H20190105                         
D0012345ACCT_12345    100001072010
D0008912ACCT_8912     450023082005
T0001245678
```

`awk` has sprintf too.  IMO this is harder to read and understand than the perl version.  YMMV.

Another `awk` version, similar to the perl version:

```
$ awk '
   /^D/ {
     ac=sprintf("%-7s",substr($0,2,7)+0);
     $0=gensub("^(D)(.{7})(.{12})","\\1\\2ACCT_"ac,1)
   }
   1' input.txt 
H20190105                         
D0012345ACCT_12345     100001072010
D0008912ACCT_8912      450023082005
T0001245678
```

---

If you didn't need the zero-padding removal, it could be done with `sed`:

```
$ sed -E -e 's/^(D)(.{7})(.{12})/\1\2ACCT_\2/' input.txt 
H20190105                         
D0012345ACCT_0012345   100001072010
D0008912ACCT_0008912   450023082005
T0001245678
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'NF>1{$0=sprintf("%sACCT_%-11d%s", substr($0,1,8), substr($0,2,7), substr($0,24))} 1' file
H20190105
D0012345ACCT_12345      100001072010
D0008912ACCT_8912       450023082005
T0001245678
```